# How to add streams to redis-benchmark tool?

Tags: redis

I understand redis benchmark tool only supports few commands, how can i add my own command like "xadd" to test performance aka rps?

Comment: did you figure out how to run custom commands using redis-benchmark? I am trying to run some similar tests.

Comment: Unless you ready to contribute in the repo, there is no way, i ended up writting my own cli app to do the same which gave me acurate results as i would use in my app..